# Varnish Apache Integration going to 503 Backend fetch failed in MAC

Tags: apache, magento2, mamp, varnish

I tried to setup varnish on MAC for apache2(MAMP) using below steps

**Step1.** brew install varnish

**Step2.** Varnished installed then configured default.vcl

```
backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
```

**Step3.** configured apache2 to run on port 8080

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>

</virtualHost>
```

**Step4.** running 127.0.0.1 or localhost give below error

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 20

Varnish cache server
```

Can anyone please tell me what step I am missing here.

Thanks

Comment: sudo varnishd -a 127.0.0.1:80 -b 127.0.0.1:8080 -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -s file,/tmp,500M works successfully but backend fetch failed

Answer (score 0):

I addressed a similar issue here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363095/magento2-4-5-varnish-alway-so-503-backend-fetch-fail/

It describes the following aspects:

- Changing the health check URL to `/healt_check.php` for recent versions of Magento
- Check the current backend health
- Debugging the output of the health check
- Considering that the health check might timeout after 2 seconds